# Error during sbt execution: java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty stream

Tags: intellij-idea

I know that the question doesn't explain the problem in detail but I don't have any more details. `IntelliJ` was working fine and now I get `Error during sbt execution: java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty stream` when I try to build the code. I have now clue what went wrong. What has gone wrong?

Comment: Too few details. Do you have a stacktrace? Are there any errors in [log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)? Try re-import project: File | New | Project from existing sources and select build.sbt file to import from.

Comment: actually, it worked!  I closed current project and reloaded it as you suggested. Happy to accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323/andrey) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293567/error-during-sbt-execution-java-util-nosuchelementexception-head-of-empty-stre#comment95408445_54293567) please try re-importing the project:  File | New | Project using `build.sbt` file to import from.